# Reverse for 'post_list' with keyword arguments '{'pk': '2'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$']

Tags: django

I think this is very easy problem but I don't know what's wrong.
I reserved the error.

It says :

**Exception Type:   NoReverseMatch**

> Exception Value:  Reverse for 'post_publish' with keyword arguments
>   '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['\^post/\(\?P(?P[^/]+)\\d\+\)/publish/\$$']
>
> Exception
>   Location: C:\Users\umts\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in
>   _reverse_with_prefix, line 622

can you guys help me to solve these problems?

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    path('post/new', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/edit/', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
    path(r'^drafts/$', views.post_draft_list, name='post_draft_list'),
    path(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/publish/$', views.post_publish, name='post_publish'),
    path(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$', views.post_remove, name='post_remove'),
    path(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/comment/$', views.comment_add, name='comment_add'),
    path(r'^comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/approve/$', views.comment_approve, name='comment_approve'),
    path(r'^comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$', views.comment_remove, name='comment_remove'),
]
```

I'll show only 'comment add' code

**views.py**

```
def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})


# comment 더하기
def comment_add(request, pk):
    post=get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form=CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html') #, {'form':form})
```

**post_detail.html**

```
      {% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="post">
    {% if post.published_date %}
      <div class="date">
        {{ post.published_date }}
      </div>
    {% else %}

      <!--버튼은 디폴트값, 기능은 post_publish-->
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'post_publish' pk=post.pk %}">
        Publish
      </a>

      <!--버튼은 디폴트값, 기능은 post_edit-->
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'post_edit' pk=post.pk %}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">
        </span>
      </a>

    <!--버튼은 디폴트값, 기능은 post_remove-->
    <a class='btn btn-default' href="{% url 'post_remove' pk=post.pk %}">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">
      </span>
    </a>

    {% endif %}

    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
  </div>


  <!--Comment 입력창-->
  <hr>
  <form action="{% url 'comment_add' pk=post.pk %}" method="POST" class="comment-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="댓글 달기...">
  </form>

  <!--
  <form class="post-form" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!--{{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">
      Add comment
    </button>
    <input type="text" name="content" value="Add Comment">
  </form>-->

  <!-- 코멘트 보기 -->
  <hr>
  {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
  {% if user.is_authenticated or comment.approved_comment %}

  <div class="comment">
    <div class="date">
      {{ comment.created_date }}
      {% if not comment.approved_comment %}
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'comment_remove' pk=comment.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'comment_approve' pk=comment.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></a>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
    {{ comment.author }}
    <p>{{ comment.text|linebreaks}}</p>
  </div>
  {% endif %}

  {% empty %}
  <p>No Comments here yet</p>
  {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

You can ignore the Korean words. However, what I want to make is add comment.

Comment: you need to show the `post_detail` view

Comment: ```post_detail.html

Comment: django view `views.post_detail`

Comment: Thank you for your kindness, Bear Brown. And I'm so sorry if I bothered you T^T